# If everything is an object, why can't I add attributes to some?

Tags: python, attributes

If everything is object, then why won't the following code work:

```
x = 6
x.newAttrib = 8
```

So it's not an object, or some limited object?

Comment: Yes, everything is an object. No, that doesn't mean all objects allow for arbitrary attributes. The two concepts are *not exclusive*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is an object not the class and class instances? What is an object then?

Comment: No, instances are a *kind* of object. But so are classes. And modules, and functions, and integers.

Comment: Objects are things with attributes that a Python program interacts with. You just can't add *new* attributes to integers.

Comment: Also see the [Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-object): *Any data with state (attributes or value) and defined behavior (methods).*

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I see. Thanks. Do you know why this question is downvoted?)))

Comment: At a guess (I can't read the minds of everyone that votes), I'd say you didn't motivate your question very well or have shared your research. Why did you expect that setting arbitrary attributes is part of what makes something  an object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, everything is an object. However, everything being an object does *not* mean that everything takes arbitrary attributes.

Integers in Python are objects, and have attributes and methods (which are just *callable* attributes):

```
>>> x = 6
>>> x.real
6
>>> x.imag
0
>>> x.bit_length()
3
```

To support arbitrary attributes, an object needs to have a `__dict__` mapping. Integers don't have such a mapping:

```
>>> x.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Other objects do, like functions, for example:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
...
>>> foo.__dict__
{}
>>> foo.bar = 'baz'
```

But a `__dict__` mapping comes with a price: a larger memory footprint for such objects. Since Python uses a *lot* of integers, it makes sense to *not* give them a `__dict__` mapping, to save memory. You *very rarely* would need to give them extra attributes anyway.

You can define your own classes that produce instances without a `__dict__` attribute, by giving your class a [`__slots__` class variable](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots); this defines the fixed attributes an instance supports. This lets you benefit from the same memory savings:

```
>>> class Demo(object):
...     __slots__ = ('foo',)
...
>>> d = Demo()
>>> d.foo = 'bar'
>>> d.bar = 'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Demo' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

And vice-versa, if you create a subclass of `int` and not give your subclass a `__slots__` variable, you can add arbitrary attributes to that subclass:

```
>>> class MyInt(int):
...     pass
...
>>> mi = MyInt(6)
>>> mi.foo = 'bar'
```

Comment: Object is any data with state (attributes or value) and defined behavior (methods). Just to complement with the definition of object.

Comment: It might be worth adding that you _can_ potentially create an object which inherits from `int` and has a dictionary.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: done, as well as covering `__slots__` in custom classes.